# How can I tell if a specific part of my Rails app is tying up my Heroku dyno?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

I just implemented `carrierwave_direct` to upload files in my app directly to S3, with the goal of avoiding tying up my Heroku dyno, per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3.

How can I confirm that I have accomplished what I set out to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Heroku account, signup for the free New Relic addon which provides some great profiling tools. Then upload a big file and check New Relic to make sure it isn't tying up your dyno.

Comment: Can you point me to where I should be looking in New Relic?  I've got it installed, and I'm seeing the upload come up in Slow Transactions, but it doesn't appear that it's tying up my dyno (I can still navigate the app in another browser even while the upload is taking place).  Just want to confirm I'm looking in the right place.

Comment: From the App Server, Overview graph (which should be what New Rlic starts on), look at the response time. If there is a big spike, especially with the blue Ruby time, then the upload is still tying up your dyno.